# Poner videos de Youtube en RecyclerView-CardView Adapter Android

Tags: android

Buenas tardes, estoy intentando poner en un CardView videos de youtube usando la API de Youtube, pero este no me muestra nada.

**Este es mi xml:**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/CardViewComoSeHace"
    android:layout_margin="9dp"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    >

    <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/youtubeThumb"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        />


        <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
            android:text="descripcion_video"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="2"
            app:minTextSize="13sp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:id="@+id/txtComoSeHace"
            android:layout_marginTop="167dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="#000"
            />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**Este es mi adaptador del RecyclerView:**

```
 public class ProductocomosehaceAdaptador extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductocomosehaceAdaptador.ProdComoseHaceViewHolder> {


private ArrayList<ProductocomosehaceBean> bean;
//Acá va la APIKEY, no lo pongo solo para no mostrarlo.
private static String API_KEY = "MyApiKey";


public ProductocomosehaceAdaptador(ArrayList<ProductocomosehaceBean> prod){
        this.bean = prod;
 }


@Override
public ProdComoseHaceViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview_recycler_comosehace,parent,false);

    return new ProdComoseHaceViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ProdComoseHaceViewHolder holder, int position) {
    //holder.imagen.setImageUrl(bean.get(position).getImagen());
    //Picasso.with(context).load(bean.get(position).getImagen()).into(holder.imagen);

    final int i = position;

    holder.descrip.setText(bean.get(position).getDescripcion());
    Log.i("Link", bean.get(position).getLink());
    Log.i("Imagen",bean.get(position).getImagen());


  //poner videos..

    YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView = (YouTubeThumbnailView) holder.view.findViewById(R.id.youtubeThumb);
    youTubeThumbnailView.initialize(API_KEY, new YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener(){


        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, final YouTubeThumbnailLoader youTubeThumbnailLoader) {
            youTubeThumbnailLoader.setVideo(bean.get(i).getLink());
            youTubeThumbnailLoader.setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(new YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onThumbnailLoaded(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, String s) {
                    youTubeThumbnailLoader.release();

                }

                @Override
                public void onThumbnailError(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader.ErrorReason errorReason) {
                    Log.e("ErrorReason", errorReason.toString());

                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

        }
    });


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return bean.size();
}

public static class ProdComoseHaceViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    CardView cardView;
    //SmartImageView imagen;
    AutofitTextView descrip;
    YouTubeThumbnailView view;



    public ProdComoseHaceViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.CardViewComoSeHace);
        //imagen = (SmartImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.SmartImageProductoComoSeHace);
        descrip = (AutofitTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtComoSeHace);
        view = (YouTubeThumbnailView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.youtubeThumb);

        Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(itemView.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf");
        descrip.setTypeface(type);

          }
       }
   }
```

Estoy obteniendo las url de los videos desde Firebase, en la parte:

**Log.i("Link", bean.get(position).getLink());** me obtiene los links perfectamente.
Este log me bota estos 2 links que funcionan correctamente:

uxVQfkW_fCk

wnUAVyhgRRo

Casi toda la información que obtengo desde Firebase funciona perfectamente, como por ejemplo la variable "descrip", eso funciona normal; lo que no funciona es a la hora de poner el video de youtube en los cardView.

**Este es el resultado que tengo ahora:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Entonces finalmente mi consulta sería, en caso esté haciendo mal a la hora de intentar poner los videos de Youtube en los CardView entonces, ¿cómo sería la forma de poner los videos?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Log.i("Link", bean.get(position).getLink()); me obtiene los links
>   perfectamente. Este log me bota estos 2 links que funcionan
>   correctamente:
>
> uxVQfkW_fCk
>
> wnUAVyhgRRo

Estas obteniendo los id de los videos mediante la API, pero lo que necesitas en realidad es la ruta de la imagen para poderla agregar al **`YouTubeThumbnailView`**, para esto necesitas completar la ruta del thumbnail:

```
https://img.youtube.com/vi/<id video>/default.jpg
```

o la primera imagen:

```
https://img.youtube.com/vi/<id video>/0.jpg
```

En el caso del ejemplo que muestras los url serían:

https://img.youtube.com/vi/uxVQfkW_fCk/default.jpg

https://img.youtube.com/vi/uxVQfkW_fCk/0.jpg

https://img.youtube.com/vi/wnUAVyhgRRo/0.jpg

https://img.youtube.com/vi/wnUAVyhgRRo/default.jpg

Comment: Genial amigo, me funcionó correctamente, una consulta final si no es mucha molestia que me tiene picando el cuerpo hace días; ¿Cómo hago para que al hacer clic al cardView se abra un AlertDialog y que dentro de eso esté el vídeo al que corresponde la imagen?. Ya sé que tengo que poner un "holder.itemView.SetOnclickListener...... y luego crear un layout personalizado para el AlertDialog, pero cómo hago para poner dentro de eso el vídeo?

Comment: seria una FragmentDialog pero si quieres reproducir el video dentro me parece que no es posible, ya que  se intentara abrir el video desde la app, tendría que revisar la Api, sería bueno agregaras una pregunta con lo que comentas tal vez alguién ha tratado de realizar esto.